# How to get to attack and defeat Alani (for the Mount)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

There is a beautiful serpent flying around the Vale of Eternal Blossoms, teasing all the Mount Collectors in the game. She is called **Alani**.

I heard that you need some shard(s) to get to remove her shield thing, but I am not sure how to get these shards or how to use them.

So basically, my question is:

- How can I get the shard(s) that I need.
- How do I use the item(s) required to be able to attack Alani.
- Is the Mount a 100% from Alani, or does it get mailed or instantly added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shards don't remove the shield, the sky crystal does. To answer your 3 questions:

**How can I get the shard(s) that I need?**
Skyshards can drop from every enemy in Pandaria. The problem is that they are really rare. The drop chance is way lower than 1% so be ready to invest some time if you really want the mount.

**How do I use the item(s) required to be able to attack Alani?**
Very simple: Once you have 10 Skyshards, click them to create a sky crystal and then find Alani, target him and Click the Sky Crystal.

**Is the mount a 100% from Alani, or does it get mailed or instantly added?**
The mount is a [100% Drop](http://www.wowhead.com/item=90655#dropped-by) but remember that it requires an exalted reputation with the August celestials! You also need Cloud Serpent riding to fly this mount.

Comment: "Skyshards can drop from every enemy in Pandaria" - All PvE Enemies on the continent of Pandaria? Does this include Raids/Instances?

Comment: @HowlinWulf I got some Skyshards from Mogushan Vaults back in the day. But I'm not sure how it works with the new raids. I think ToT and SoO don't drop shards. The easiest place to farm is The Vale of  Eternal Blossoms, since really every NPC can drop them. I think there are some exceptions to Pandaria but really not too many (I remember looting one from monkeys right at the launch of MoP in the first area)

Comment: The Skyshards drop almost exclusively in the Vale of Eternal Blossoms (see on [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/item=86547#dropped-by)). I even think all other areas are bugs (in Wowhead's data gathering or in Wow itself).

Comment: I've leveled 3 toons to 90 (incl doing vale quests) and done dailies until Golden Lotus Exalted on one; and have a grand total of 1 shard.

Comment: Corollary question: if you fail to kill Alani do you have to get another 10 shards to try again, or what?